# How to avoid Double NAT?

Tags: networking, nat

I have a modem/router supplied by my ISP. The optical fiber connects to it and Internet and telephone lines come out of it. Unfortunately, the DNS server settings on ISP router are fixed and cannot be changed. This is the way ISP ensures that specific sites can be blocked if any government regulation comes in (Dumb... I know).

I want to use Google DNS/Open DNS for my network so I had two options - change DNS setting on every device which connects to the router or set up a router in front of it and set DNS on it. I opted for second option but this had led to Double NAT situation. Port forwarding has become a pain.

Is there any other way I can change DNS setting globally without making my network double NAT?

Comment: Who is your ISP? What model modem are you using?

Comment: I am in India using BSNL Broadband. The router doesn't specify any model no, just that it is GPON ONT (Gigabit-capable Passive Optical Network | Optical Network Terminal).

Comment: Your router probably has a DHCP server. Can it be turned off? Are other DNS servers even reachable when you set them directly on a device?

Comment: I can turn off DHCP on ISP router. DNS settings on device work. For e.g. some torrent sites which are blocked when I use ISP router directly work in my double NAT configuration.

Comment: What make and model is the additional router you installed? Can it run OpenWrt?

Comment: My personal wireless router is Asus RT-N12LX. I don't think it supports OpenWrt.

Comment: That seems to be the case. My suggestion would be to simply set up a custom DHCP server, but that requires proper access. Integrated DHCP servers virtually always advertise themselves as the gateway, which won’t work here. Do you have anything else that runs Linux and doesn’t hurt your power bill too much?

Answer (score 2):

The device in the middle could act as a transparent bridge for most traffic, thereby not affecting any IP addresses.  Yet, similar to a firewall blocking traffic, it could also block DHCP traffic.  That will allow you to run your own DHCP server (on the transparent bridge, or on any other device on your local network).  DHCP is the protocol typically used for handing out IPv4 settings including which DNS server to use.

So, it's possible.  Precise steps will vary based on what kind of device you insert.  (Perhaps a better, more clear way of saying that is that the required steps will depend on what operating system is running on the device that acts as this transparent bridge.)

Different devices may have different abilities to support the functionality described.

**Update #1:** You changed things significantly.  You have now described a scenario where a much more commonly supported (more easily implementable) approach will accomplish what you said you seek.  The details provided by your latest comments have opened a door to another possibility that will be easier to do.  I expect this to be good news.

First, check the settings of the DHCP server on the ISP router.  Figure out what addresses it hands out (and what the subnet size/mask is).  Such details may be useful later.

You said you can turn off DHCP on the ISP router.  Okay.  Do that.  Then run a DHCP server on literally any other device on the LAN.  So if you want to use your Asus RT-N12LX to be the DHCP server, you don't need to have that device be between the ISP router and the rest of the LAN.  Simply plug it into the LAN.

The trick, which will probably be simpler to support, is to have the DHCP server provide the settings you want, including the Default Gateway setting (which should be the ISP router's internal IP address), and the desired DNS settings.  The addresses handed out should be in the same subnet as the ISP router's internal IP address.  As an example, if using the common IPv4 subnet size of /24 (subnet mask of 255.255.255.0), and the ISP router uses 192.168.1.1, then have the DHCP server hand out similar-ish addresses like 192.168.1.10 through 192.168.1.200.

**Update #2**: 
So your router is also being used as an access point.  Okay, that does pose a slight complication with Update #1's plan.  The access point should probably be a DHCP server for the Wi-Fi devices.

Your WLAN (Wireless LAN) does want DHCP enabled on that Asus router.
Your wired LAN does not.  Can you easily disable the DHCP server on just the wired LAN, but leave it enabled on the wireless LAN?

If so, you're golden.  Run two DHCP servers, and make sure they don't overlap.  For example, if the ISP router has an internal IP address of 192.168.1.1, then have the ISP router hand out addresses of 192.168.1.10 through 192.168.1.99 and have the other device hand out addresses of 192.168.1.100 through 192.168.1.199.  (Adjust as appropriate.  Fore example, if the ISP router ISP router has an internal IP address of 192.168.0.1, then have the ISP router hand out addresses of 192.168.0.10 through 192.168.0.99 and have the other device hand out addresses of 192.168.0.100 through 192.168.0.199.  Just have the first three octets match.  This works if you're using the common subnet size of IPv4 /24 (using a netmask of 255.255.255.0).

Comment: My personal wireless router is Asus RT-N12LX. When I put it in Bridge mode, I cannot specify any DNS setting on it.

Comment: @Mayank: Yes, you would have to set up a few firewall rules instead.

Comment: So you are saying turning off DHCP on ISP router and having my Asus router do DHCP will remove the first NAT. Will the IPs distributed by Asus router be visible to ISP router? My confusion is because only the Asus router has wireless capability (not ISP one), so that's the router my devices connect to.